# DataGridView - Proportional Sizing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForm project with a tab control container and several tabs.  On 1 tab, I have 2 grids, one on top of the other.  The grids stretch all the way across the form when fully maximized or when floating (minimized but not hidden).  That part works exactly how I want it to.

However, I want the grids to size proportionally on the vertical axis.  I cant find a way to set a % for the height of the grid.  Is there some other trick to achieving this?  Any tips on what property or combination that I might need to set or investigate?  Sorry, I know not much to go on, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tab control also maximizing or not when you fully maximized ?

Comment: Yes.  Everything except the height of the grid is changing.

Comment: Have you tried the Anchor properties? If you anchor the DataFridView on all four sides its height will change as the form/container changes size. Answer below using tablelayoutpanel is probably the way to go if you are truly talking about proportion. Splitter control is another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps, it will work fine.

1. Place tablelayoutpanel control in tabcontrol.
2. Set rows and columns for tablelayoutpanel using the "Edit Rows/Columns"
3. If you have 2 datagridviews only in this tabcontrol, then set row count 1,column count 1.
4. Set column1 with Percentage 100 ,row1 with 50%, row2 with 50%
5. Set tablelayoutpanel dock property to fill.
6. drag and drop datagridview1 to tablelayoutpanel row1 and set the dock property to fill.
7. drag and drop datagridview2 to tablelayoutpanel row2 and set the dock property to fill.

Comment: I went with this method. I had to add panels to each row since I had multiple controls on the form in addition to the girds.  I didnt mention them in the question, but it makes a difference if you have search and save features or whatever.  Adding panels and the tablelayout control did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: It's glad to help you. Happy coding.